# How to keep link at the bottom using flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

We have to display blocks of content in many rows with max 3 columns. Each block of content contains a `heading`, `description`, and `link`. We are using `flexbox` to display the blocks in a row such that the height of the row is taken up by the tallest element. However, we are not able to always align the `link` at the bottom and it always seems to be place right below each `description`.

How can we align the link in the bottom of each block and have each block still be the height of the tallest block using `flexbox`?

**Here is what we have tried**: https://codepen.io/userrj/pen/WYXoOO

**Code explained**:

1. each block is surrounded by `.bkg--grey` so you can see the block is taking the height of the tallest block as expected.
2. `border` is added to each element with `flex__item` so you can see how much space it is taking up.
3. each block contains: `heading`, `description`, and `link` from `top down (column)`

**Current issue:**

[image: current issue link at the bottom]

**Desired output**

[image: desired output link at the bottom]

We are hoping to not use `float` or `position: absolute` to get this done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make `article` a flex container and adjust some alignment:

```
article {
  display: flex;
}
.flex__item > div:last-child {
  margin-top:auto;
}
```

Full code:

```css
.flex__item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.flex__col {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.flex__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
.flex__item {
  padding: 16px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.bkg--grey {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.col--sm-12 {
  width: 100%;
}
.col--md-6 {
  width: 50%;
}
.col--lg-4 {
  width: 33.33%;
}
/*added this*/
article {
  display: flex;
}
.flex__item > div:last-child {
  margin-top:auto;
}
/**/

[class*=col--] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 16px;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex__wrapper">
 <div class="col--sm-12 col--md-6 col--lg-4 flex__col">
  <article class="bkg--grey">
   <div class="flex__item">
    <div>
     <h4>Some Efficiently</h4>
     <p>Efficiently enhance frictionless markets without distinctive deliverables. </p>
    </div>
    <div><a href="#">Read More</a></div>
   </div>
  </article>
 </div>
 <div class="col--sm-12 col--md-6 col--lg-4 flex__col">
  <article class="bkg--grey">
   <div class="flex__item">
    <div>
     <h4>Some Objectively promote</h4>
     <p>Objectively promote enterprise-wide strategic theme areas rather than process-centric catalysts for change. Completely procrastinate sticky best practices and corporate sources. Distinctively unleash superior metrics via go forward alignments. Uniquely reconceptualize plug-and-play e-services through collaborative solutions. Progressively maximize adaptive experiences with. </p>
    </div>
    <div><a href="#">Read More</a></div>
   </div>
  </article>
 </div>
 <div class="col--sm-12 col--md-6 col--lg-4 flex__col">
  <article class="bkg--grey">
   <div class="flex__item">
    <div>
     <h4>Completely create</h4>
     <p>Completely create equity invested relationships for client-focused paradigms. Distinctively benchmark exceptional information before corporate materials. Compellingly pontificate 2.0. </p>
    </div>
    <div><a href="#">Read More</a></div>
   </div>
  </article>
 </div>
 <div class="col--sm-12 col--md-6 col--lg-4 flex__col">
  <article class="bkg--grey">
   <div class="flex__item">
    <div>
     <h4>Distinctively deliver</h4>
     <p>Distinctively deliver one-to-one potentialities with excellent resources. Collaboratively.</p>
    </div>
    <div><a href="#">Read More</a></div>
   </div>
  </article>
 </div>
 <div class="col--sm-12 col--md-6 col--lg-4 flex__col">
  <article class="bkg--grey">
   <div class="flex__item">
    <div>
     <h4>Authoritatively facilitate</h4>
     <p>Authoritatively facilitate sustainable portals through cross-platform catalysts for change. Monotonectally transform e-business total linkage without front-end action items.</p>
    </div>
    <div><a href="#">Read More</a></div>
   </div>
  </article>
 </div>
</section>
```